# non understandable key switches in jazz

Tags: guitar, jazz

I am trying to learn jazz. I got a handbook with some jazz standards. Given a jazz tab, is there a dominant key ? like in classical music. I don't understand the structure of the music. For instance, there are many II, V, I in a same tab but seems to me that have nothing to do with each other

Comment: Jazz standards are typically in a key, but the harmonic structures don't necessarily adhere to the same rules as in classical music. As asked, though, your question is too broad to generate meaningful answers. Consider asking about a specific section of a specific tune that's giving you trouble.

Comment: can you give an example of a `ii V I` pair that isn't making sense? Giving a specific song title and the confusing passage will be much more helpful, than generalizations.

Answer (score 5):

For many standard there is a dominant key.  Like in classical music there are modulations to other keys, like the IV and the relative minor vi.  But the key is indicated at the start of the piece by a set of flats or sharps that follow the same pattern as in any western musical tradition.

The abundance of ii/V you mention is likely due to what is called a cycle extension.  It is a common practice to take any chord in the "key" and fill in movement with a relative ii-V or some variant based on the circle progression, you may also see iii-vi-ii-V, etc.

For example if one wants to jump from I to IV you would create a richer sound by passing through the I7 (the V7 of the IV degree), I-->I7-->IV.  You could also walk back and cycle with a full ii-V, I-->v-->I7-->IV, etc.  clearly the minor chord on V would be disconcerting but if approached gracefully will add a lot of interesting harmony to the progression.

These devices are all over classical music, renaissance music, etc.  So it's really nothing new.  If you are interested in digging deeper I'd recommend Modulation by Max Reger, but work through a basic harmony book first as Reger is quite dense.

Answer (score 3):

You've already identified the ii/V/I progressions, so the question is how the Is are related to each other.

Some jazz tunes are pretty straightforward, following a natural harmonic series (the circle of fifths/fourths).  So if the first I is Cmaj7 and the second I is Fmaj7, you're moving counterclockwise around the circle, and if the second is Gmaj7 you're moving clockwise.

Other modulations are harder to see.  A tune like Giant Steps has Bmaj7, Ebmaj7, and Gmaj7 as the I chords.  But if you connect those on a circle of fifths, you'll see they form a triangle.  That's sometimes called a "geometric modulation"

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, jazz tunes are in a particular key. Most tunes will modulate in some way, and then end in the original key (or the relative major/minor).

One of the differences with "classical music" (by which I mean common practice in the Mozart era) is that there are two types of dominant chord - functioning and non-functioning. For a beginner, these can make it very confusing to identify the proper key.

For example, "Our Love is Here to Stay" in the key of Db will start on an `Eb7`, but then move to `Ebm7 - Ab7 - Dbmaj7`. The actual key of the piece is Db, but clearly the first `Eb7` is not the dominant of that key. Therefore Eb7 is a non-functioning dominant. There are thousands of other examples like this in the Real Book. Functioning dominants will often have alterations (b9, #9, #5, alt) whereas non-functioning dominants will usually have only 7, 9 or occasionally the #11.

There are also cases where the piece will start on a degree other than the tonic - for example "Just Friends" starts on chord IV of the key.

If you try to look for ii-V-Is that resolve to a major (for a piece in a major key), those are usually a good indicator of the key at that point in the piece. If you find something really unusual or that you don't understand then you can post the specific chord sequence as a question on this forum and someone will try to analyze it for you.

Jazz chord progressions are not infinite - there are a limited number of "moves" that commonly occur which make up the majority of the harmony found in standard tunes. A good place to learn these foundational moves is through the book "Harmony with Lego Bricks" by Conrad Cork or the more recent ["Insights in Jazz" by John Elliot](https://dropback.co.uk/the-book/). Both of these books are aimed at making it easier to understand chord sequences in jazz contexts.